# Re-entering Schengen Area before expiration of my Swedish visa

Tags: visas, schengen, sweden

I am Hong Kongese, studying in Sweden. I have a Hong Kong SAR passport which allows me visa-free access to Schengen countries for 90 days. I also have a Swedish residence permit.

I read in other discussion forums that I can enjoy 90-days visa free entry to the Schengen Area if I re-enter Schengen from a non-Schengen area after expiry of my residence permit. If I want to travel to other Schengen countries before the day of expiry of my residence permit, can I still get an 90-days visa-free?

My plan is leave Sweden 10 days before expiry and go to the UK. Then I will travel to Norway as a tourist, entering 4 days before the expiry of my permit. Can I get 90-days visa-free stay by following this plan even when my residence permit will not have expired when I enter Norway?

Answer (score 2):

It is **in practice unclear** whether one needs to leave and re-enter the Schengen area in order to continue traveling in the area as a tourist after the expiry of a national long-stay visa or residence permit.

Reading the actual Schengen regulations, I cannot find anything that implies such a requirement. However, several people have independently related on this site that they were told by border/immigration officials they would need to do to that. So it would appear that, at the least, there's a risk that if you *don't* make a visa run, you may run into trouble when you leave the Area because you run into a border guard who *thinks* you need to do it. Perhaps the trouble would be cleared up when their superior gets involved, perhaps not.

In any case, the only halfway reasonable purpose of requiring a visa run would be to get an entry stamp in your passport that marks the beginning of your *stay **not** under the residence permit*.  Thus, as long as you *enter* the Schengen area at another country than Sweden and do not actually go to Sweden, I think even confused border guards ought to allow starting the 90/180 day count at that day, even if your Swedish residence permit was still valid at that time.

Of course, you should also be sure to follow the *actual* 90/180 day rule, which says that every day where you have been in a Schengen country other than Sweden counts, no matter whether you went there from Sweden or indirectly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking to get an entry stamp is the best way. However, I found that I got an entry stamp when I entry to Sweden as well, even I have residence visa.